# Change zoom in out icon color of google map

Tags: javascript

I want to change the color of zoom in out and the fullscreen button icon gray to white. But, I can't change color with CSS as these icon's format is SVG. is it possible to change color?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the button color using CSS. Just select the CSS class and use the CSS filter property

```
#map .gm-fullscreen-control > img:nth-child(1) {
    filter: brightness(3.5) !important;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(3.5) !important;
}
```

I hope it will be helpful for others :)